# How can I associate special logic with file extensions?

Tags: text-processing, editors

Is there an easy way to have arbitrary text editors call special logic  based on a file extension?

For example, let's say I had a zip file that had a collection of files.

```
text.txt
image.jpg
othercrap.crap
```

Is there a way to have text editors automatically run commands when opening the file via something like `vi myarchive.zip` based on the file extension?

Comment: sounds like taskwarrior

Comment: Since everyone seems to be hung up on the backstory I'll trim the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand a lot of your description other than "it would just be slick if I could just use vi on it and the text parts would automatically know how to format themselves" but this might be what you're trying to do (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' 0

edit_zip() {
    unzip "$1" > "$tmp" &&
    vi "$tmp" &&
    zip "$tmp" > "$1"
}

edit_pdf() {
    pdf2text "$1" > "$tmp" &&
    vi "$tmp" &&
    text2pdf "$tmp" > "$1"
}

act_ext="${1}_${2##*.}"
if declare -F "$act_ext" > /dev/null; then
    "$act_ext" "$3"
else
    printf 'Operation "%s" not supported.\n' "$*"
fi
```

The above would be the contents of `myprog` which you'd call as `myprog edit myfile.zip` as shown in your question.

`unzip` and `zip` above may not take exactly those args or be exactly the commands you want to run on a zip file and `pdf2text` and `text2pdf` may not really exist or really do what you'd want to edit a PDF, the above is just to give you the idea of writing a separate function to do whatever it is you want to do per operation (action+extension) you want to support, e.g. `edit` and `.zip`, etc. and then having that appropriate function be automatically called based on the arguments passed to your script.

Answer (score -1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

A. You can design/run your own class `Proc` objects, which are representations of external command calls. Save below as a script and run:

```
my $proc = run 'echo', 'Hallo world', :out;
my $captured-output = $proc.out.slurp: :close;
say "Output was $captured-output.raku()";# OUTPUT: «Output was "Hallo world\n"␤»
```

B. Maybe you don't want to get your shell involved, so instead you can write your own Raku one-liners and point them at files in a particular `dir()` directory. Below returns `.jpeg` files and their creation dates, one line per `.jpeg` file:

```
~$ raku -e 'for dir( test => /:i '.' jpe?g $/ ) -> $file {
            say join "\t", $file, $file.IO.created.DateTime;
            }
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Proc
https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir

---

C. Raku has the Ake module/script, which is useful for designing/running tasks:

```
~/Ake_Morning$ cat Akefile
task 'buy-food', {
    say 'Bought a salad.'
}

task 'shower', {
    say 'Showered.'
}

task 'morning' => <shower buy-food>;

task 'dinner' => <buy-food>, {
    say 'Yummy!'
}
```

Then run the `ake` binary on the `Akefile`:

```
~/Ake_Morning$ ake
Task “default” does not exist

Did you mean one of these?
    buy-food
    dinner
    help
    morning
    shower
~/Ake_Morning$ ake morning
Showered.
Bought a salad.
```

https://github.com/Raku/ake

---

D. Raku also has the Sparrow6 (DSL) and Tomtit (task-runner) Ecosystem, which appears to be `yaml`-based. Sparrow can run tasks for you in 6 different languages: 1. Raku, 2. Perl, 3. Bash, 4. Python, 5. Ruby, and 6. Powershell.

https://github.com/melezhik/Tomtit
https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/dsl.md
https://raku.org

Comment: So I voted down initially because I wasn't asking for a suggestions for command line task managers, but then I saw that my question probably had more info than necessary. I wanted to undo my vote because I do appreciate the suggestion, but now it's too late. I'm sorry